# No se pueden enviar correos usando php en una instancia de google cloud

Tags: php, email

Más específico: estoy usando una instalacion de centos 7, uso php 5.6 y estoy tratando de enviar emails usando algunos componentes de joomla, específiamente chrono forms 5, debido a que no se reporta ningún error al enviar un formulario desde un sitio web, pero tampoco llegan los correos, hice una prueba usando un código simple de email:

```
    <?php
if (@mail("tuemail@tudominio.com", "Probando email en php", "Esto es una prueba a ver si funciona el mail en php")) {
echo('<p>Email enviado.</p>');
} else {
echo('<p>Email NO ENVIADO.</p>');
}
?>
```

Este código no envía ningún correo, pero tampoco genera ningún error.

He leído en algún lado que desde Google Cloud, es necesario usar un servicio de terceros para enviar correos, pero la verdad es que no encuentro nada útil o al menos entendible para poder hacer que el servidor envíe un email.

He probado en otro servidor (hostgator) con las configuraciones similares al de Google Cloud, y allí funciona correctamente.

Por favor ayuda, esto es importante, pues un sitio que no es capaz de enviar formularios de sus visitantes, es un sitio que no esta al 100 %.

Comment: Buen día, encontraron solución a este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Ola, bueno te cuento que yo tengo un problema  similar y lo que he encontrado es que google cloud bloquea el puerto de salida smtp (puerto 25) por temas de  seguridad y es imposible desbloquearlo, estoy tratando de ver como se hace para redireccionar la salida de email por otro puerto

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud no permite el envío por puerto 25, puedes utilizar alguna api como mandrill o sendgrid para lograrlo sin problema alguno.

Esta medida de seguridad es tomada por muchos datacenters ya que el envío de emails es considerado abusivo y mucha gente se aprovecha para hacer spam.